# Returning Exception in Boolean method C#

Tags: c#, exception, boolean-logic

Below is the Code Sample which explains my issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Program.Sample();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("InvalidOperation Exception");
            }
        }

        static bool Sample()
        {
            int a = 1; int b = 2;
            if (a == b) //Some Condition checking
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            { //Is this Proper returning Exception In Boolean method instead of False
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am catching this Exception in Client Applications and Displaying an Message I would like to know whether this is proper way of doing it or not?

Comment: Yes, this is how to do work with Exceptions, as you will learn from any C# programming course.

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information to help you here. The error throwing and handling (using the Try/Catch) is certainly an OK approach. However, under what circumstances would your 'Sample' method return false?

Comment: That certainly shows *how* to use an exception, but I would say it does not represent a good example of *when* to use one.

Comment: InvalidOperationException isn't a good choice of exception. It's supposed to be used when a method call is invalid for the object's current state (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I think your sample code is too simplified as comments and answers suggest. Your method will always throw currently and has logic that has constant results. Are `a` and `b` actually parameters passed in? Also you should be catching the `InvalidOperationException` and not just `Exception`. At the moment if a different exception is thrown you will still be oroudly proclaiming it is an invalid operation exception..... So what you are doing isn't right but is probably also not what you are actually wanting to do anyway so the question is a bit hard to answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use exceptions for normal flow of control, if possible. Except for system failures and operations with potential race conditions, framework designers should design APIs so that users can write code that does not throw exceptions. For example, you can provide a way to check preconditions before calling a member so that users can write code that does not throw exceptions.

Consider terminating the process by calling System.Environment.FailFast(System.String) (a .NET Framework version 2.0 feature) instead of throwing an exception, if your code encounters a situation where it is unsafe to continue executing.

Answer (score 5):

Exceptions should be thrown when exceptional circumstance occur or a usage error is encountered, i.e. null parameter In your case it would be better to just return `false`.

Comment: I don't agree with the `return false`. This would depend on the method's functionality and the overall architecture. But I can't support a general `return false`.

Comment: @Nico The code provided does not show enough justification for throwing an exception, given that `return false` does the job perfectly well (better, in fact), and far more clearly.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Even with the given code? If it was returning false somewhere I might agree but a method that never returns false really needs to think hard about what its doing. Throwing an exception instead of returning false (as the comment suggests is the case) seems wrong to me.

Comment: You're totally right. But the meaning of the return value is unclear. If it is an actual result, then it should not be used as a status code (and the exception would be better). If it is meant as a status code, the `return false` is just fine.